# Use capifony to deploy to multiple production servers

Tags: capifony

I have managed to successfully deploy my Symfony2 application to a production web server, but cannot find any documentation on how to deploy to multiple servers with one deploy command.  In fact, at this stage it seems that my only option is to have multiple checkouts with separate config files.  Is this really the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to http://capifony.org/

**Update:**

Here you can find a sample of how to set it up.

[Deploying a Rails App to Multiple Servers using Capistrano - Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices)

Comment: I read the whole page and it doesn't make mention of deploying to more than one server at a time

Comment: You're right.

Here is an example of how to it with capistrano, maybe this will work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices

Comment: Don't put your improved answer in a comment, edit it into the answer.

Comment: @rjmunro it added to the answer now ;)

Answer (score -1):

I meet this issue and found the solution from Capifony, please try it [Capifony: deployment in clustered machines](http://capifony.org/cookbook/deployment-in-clustered-machines.html)
You just prepare your servers, and setup with Capifony

`cap HOSTS="machine1.domain, machine2.domain" deploy:setup`

And after that, always use HOSTS variable for your deploy command:

`cap HOSTS="machine1.domain, machine2.domain" deploy`

or deploy multistage command:

`cap HOSTS="machine1.domain, machine2.domain" stage_name deploy`

Comment: Great, looks a lot better now.