# Need application to deploy my software to clients (symfony2)

Tags: ruby, symfony, deployment, capistrano, capifony

i am looking for some piece of software that would be able to deploy my symfony2 application to a customer, i tried capifony but it seems that it's a big hassle to deploy to different host with different settings.

I hope i have provided enough information, i've spent a lot of time searching for a decent solution but i couldn't manage to find one.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't know why Capifony doesn't fit you. What do you really need?

Comment: I need an application that is able to deploy to different hosts (not at the same time) with different credentials and i can't seem to configure that with capifony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an answer.

Another stackoverflow mate did the same question here: [Use capifony to deploy to multiple production servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072916/use-capifony-to-deploy-to-multiple-production-servers)

And they gave him the answer, linking this other question: [Deploying a Rails App to Multiple Servers using Capistrano - Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices)

I hope I helped you, mate ;)

**Edit:**

I didn't realize that you told me "not at the same time". But, if I'm not wrong, could be another solution:

Forget about I told you, get the deploy.rb as standard as possible. Then, if you delete de line where the host is specified (and also user and pass), each time you deploy with capifony you'll be asked to enter the host (and then the user, and then the pass)

Maybe isn't the cleanest solution, but I think it could work...

Comment: Okay thanks, it's a close as it can get :)

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

It think you need the capistrano multi-stage extension:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

I use it with Capifony to deploy to test, staging and live environments for all my symfony 2 projects.