# How can i execute capistrano task in sequence for multiple server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I have multiple servers and capistrano tasks below

```
before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister'
before 'deploy:finishing',  'elb:register'

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
after 'deploy:failed',     'elb:deregister'
```

When i deploy now like below

```
  before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister' -> server1
  before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister' -> server1

  ...
  ...
```

How to deploy in sequence like below

Server1

```
  before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister'
  before 'deploy:finishing',  'elb:register'

  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
  after 'deploy:failed',     'elb:deregister'
```

Server2

```
  before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister'
  before 'deploy:finishing',  'elb:register'

  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
  after 'deploy:failed',     'elb:deregister'
```

Comment: Why not just `role :app, "machine1.mydomain.com", "machine2.mydomain.com", "machine3.mydomain.com"`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here.

Let's say you have cap config like this:

```
server 'server_1', user: 'deploy', roles: %w[app db web]
server 'server_2', user: 'deploy', roles: %w[app]
```

## Do it manually.

You can do this;

- comment out the server_2 line and run `cap production deploy`
- restore server_2 line and comment out the server_1 line and run `cap production deploy`

It's silly while useful and dead simple.

## Use different deploy env.

You can set up another deploy env like production2 and run `cap production deploy; cap production2 deploy`

## Use different deploy role.

Give your server different roles and change your tasks and config like this:

```
server 'server_1', user: 'deploy', roles: %w[app db web server_1]
server 'server_2', user: 'deploy', roles: %w[app server_2]

namespace elb do
  task ::deregister_1 do
    on roles(:server_1) do
      ...
    end
  end


  task ::deregister_2 do
    on roles(:server_2) do
      ...
    end
  end
end


before 'deploy:starting',   'elb:deregister_2'
before 'elb:deregister_2',   'elb:deregister_1'
```